# I am making a text editor using ReactQuill for iOS, however I keep on getting this issue- Unable to resolve module 'react-dom.js'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, text-editor, react-quill

My code:

```
    import React from "react";
    import ReactQuill from 'react-quill'
    import 'quill/dist/quill.snow.css'

    const Article = () => {
  
      var modules = {
        toolbar: [
          [{ size: ["small", false, "large", "huge"] }],
          ["bold", "italic", "underline", "strike", "blockquote"],
          [{ list: "ordered" }, { list: "bullet" }],
          ["link", "image"],
          [
            { list: "ordered" },
            { list: "bullet" },
            { indent: "-1" },
            { indent: "+1" },
            { align: [] }
          ],
          [{ "color": ["#000000", "#e60000", "#ff9900", "#ffff00", "#008a00", "#0066cc", "#9933ff",       "#ffffff", "#facccc", "#ffebcc", "#ffffcc", "#cce8cc", "#cce0f5", "#ebd6ff", "#bbbbbb", "#f06666", "#ffc266", "#ffff66", "#66b966", "#66a3e0", "#c285ff", "#888888", "#a10000", "#b26b00", "#b2b200", "#006100", "#0047b2", "#6b24b2", "#444444", "#5c0000", "#663d00", "#666600", "#003700", "#002966",   "#3d1466", 'custom-color'] }],
        ]
      };

      var formats = [
        "header", "height", "bold", "italic",
        "underline", "strike", "blockquote",
        "list", "color", "bullet", "indent",
        "link", "image", "align", "size",
      ];

      const handleProcedureContentChange = (content) => {
        console.log("content---->", content);
      };

      return (
         <div >
          <h1 style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>Text Editor In React JS</h1>
          <div style={{ display: "grid", justifyContent: "center"}}>
            <ReactQuill
              theme="snow"
              modules={modules}
              formats={formats}
              placeholder="write your content ...."
              onChange={handleProcedureContentChange}
              style={{ height: "220px" }}
            >
            </ReactQuill>
          </div>
        </div>

     );

    }

    export default Article;
```

I first imported react-dom.js by accident, and ever since, its giving out an error saying it cannot resolve the module, i deleted it from package.json, but the problem still persists.
I also tried to import quill/dist/quill.snow.css, but Snack is unable to resolve the dependency. I am running the code on expo v48.0.0, since the newer versions do not work on iOS.
i am expecting the output to be something like this:
[Text editor, expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPLYC.png)